# Discrepancy between T-SQL and SSRS results

Tags: t-sql, group-by, ssrs-tablix

I created the following code in T-SQL(see below)
It is working good in SSMS environment, but, when I post it into SSRS (Reporting Services) the numbers for **[Total]** and **[Completed]** fields are very different in SSRS than it is in SSMS - much higher than in SSMS

This is my code:

```
     USE [WH]
     GO

       DECLARE @MonthBOP date = '05-01-2019'
       DECLARE @MonthEOP date = '05-01-2019'
       DECLARE @EHRRegionsWHID int = -1
       DECLARE @EHRProgramsWHID int = -1
       DECLARE @EHRProgramTypesWHID int = -1


    SELECT        
          ehrrgn.WHID AS [EHRRegionWHID] 
        , ehrrgn.EHRRegion 
        , ehrprgtype.WHID AS [EHRProgramTypeWHID] 
        , ehrprg.WHID AS [EHRProgramWHID]
        , ehrprg.EHRProgramCode
        , ehrprg.EHRProgramName 
        , poswh.WHID AS [PositionWHWHID]
        , poswh.PositionNameWH
        , posfamwh.WHID AS [PositionFamilyWHWHID]
        , posfamwh.PositionFamilyNameWH
        , pos.WHID AS [PositionWHID]
        , empl.EmployeeCode
        , empl.EmployeeName
        , ct.ServiceDate
        , dd.YearMonthSort
        , ct.StaffFK
        , COUNT(ct.ServiceFK) AS [Completed]
        , tt.Total

   FROM          
       Fact.EHRClinicalTransaction ct
       INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRProgram ehrprg ON 
                       ct.ProgramFK = ehrprg.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRRegion ehrrgn ON 
                       ehrprg.EHRRegionFK = ehrrgn.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRProgramType ehrprgtype ON 
                       ehrprg.EHRProgramTypeFK = ehrprgtype.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRStaff ehrstf ON ct.StaffFK = ehrstf.WHID 

       INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomEmployee empl ON 
                       ehrstf.PaycomEmployeeFK = empl.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPosition pos ON 
                       empl.PaycomPositionFK = pos.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPositionWH poswh ON 
                       pos.PositionWHFK = poswh.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPositionFamilyWH posfamwh ON 
                       pos.PositionFamilyWHFK = posfamwh.WHID

       INNER JOIN Dimension.[Date] dd ON ct.ServiceDate = dd.[Date]

       INNER JOIN 
                ( 
                 SELECT 
                       ct.[StaffFK] 
                      ,COUNT(ct.[ServiceFK]) AS [Total]

                 FROM 
                     Fact.EHRClinicalTransaction ct
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRProgram ehrprg ON 
                                      ct.ProgramFK = ehrprg.WHID 
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRRegion ehrrgn ON 
                                    ehrprg.EHRRegionFK = ehrrgn.WHID
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRProgramType ehrprgtype ON 
                             ehrprg.EHRProgramTypeFK = ehrprgtype.WHID
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.EHRStaff ehrstf ON 
                            ct.StaffFK = ehrstf.WHID 
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomEmployee empl ON 
                            ehrstf.PaycomEmployeeFK = empl.WHID
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPosition pos ON 
                            empl.PaycomPositionFK = pos.WHID
                     INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPositionWH poswh ON 
                            pos.PositionWHFK = poswh.WHID
                 INNER JOIN Dimension.PaycomPositionFamilyWH posfamwh ON 
                            pos.PositionFamilyWHFK = posfamwh.WHID
                 INNER JOIN Dimension.[Date] dd ON 
                            ct.ServiceDate = dd.[Date]

              WHERE
                    (ct.[ServiceDate] BETWEEN @MonthBOP AND @MonthEOP) 
               AND ((ehrrgn.WHID IN (@EHRRegionsWHID)) OR 
                    (-1 IN (@EHRRegionsWHID))) AND (ehrrgn.WHID <>-1)
               AND ((ehrprg.WHID IN (@EHRProgramsWHID)) OR 
                    (-1 IN (@EHRProgramsWHID))) AND (ehrprg.WHID <>-1)
               AND ((ehrprgtype.WHID IN (@EHRProgramTypesWHID)) OR 
               (-1 IN (@EHRProgramTypesWHID))) AND (ehrprgtype.WHID <>-1)

           GROUP BY
                  ct.[StaffFK] 

             ) tt ON  ct.StaffFK = tt.StaffFK

  WHERE        
       (ct.IsNoShow = 0) 
  AND (ct.IsDeleted = 0)
  AND (ct.[ServiceDate] BETWEEN @MonthBOP AND @MonthEOP) 
  AND ((ehrrgn.WHID IN (@EHRRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@EHRRegionsWHID))) 
  AND (ehrrgn.WHID <>-1)
  AND ((ehrprg.WHID IN (@EHRProgramsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@EHRProgramsWHID))) 
  AND (ehrprg.WHID <>-1)
  AND ((ehrprgtype.WHID IN (@EHRProgramTypesWHID)) OR 
       (-1 IN (@EHRProgramTypesWHID))) AND (ehrprgtype.WHID <>-1)
   AND (ct.ServiceFK NOT IN (1, 19, 31, 49, 64, 83, 85, 86, 87, 111, 131, 
                             133, 134, 137, 139, 
        140, 141, 165, 167, 168, 171, 173, 174, 175, 198, 436, 442, 443, 
                          503, 522, 540, 541))

 GROUP BY 
          ehrrgn.WHID 
        , ehrrgn.EHRRegion 
        , ehrprgtype.WHID  
        , ehrprg.WHID 
        , ehrprg.EHRProgramCode
        , ehrprg.EHRProgramName 
        , poswh.WHID 
        , poswh.PositionNameWH
        , posfamwh.WHID 
        , posfamwh.PositionFamilyNameWH
        , pos.WHID 
        , empl.EmployeeCode
        , empl.EmployeeName
        , ct.ServiceDate
        , dd.YearMonthSort
        , ct.StaffFK 
        , tt.Total
```

Why in SSRS they jumped so high?

Here is my SSRS "Design":

[image]

And here is the result-example in SSRS:
While these numbers (half-circled in red) are so high, they are very small
(and correct, after auditing) in SSMS (t-sql):
[image]

Please help or advice!

PS-
You can click on the pictures to see it larger

Comment: Note: `DECLARE @MonthBOP date = '05-01-2019'` don't format dates that way. Always declare them `YYYYMMDD` which is locale neutral.

Comment: Check SQL Profiler to see what query is executed for showing the report? and share us that query too. thanks